# inAppPurchase.restorePurchases() takes forever to restore purchases

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I am using Flutter's [in-app-purchases][1] package to handle subscriptions inside my app. It worked great until I tried to use `inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();` to restore the previous purchases. It sometimes works and sometimes just keeps on loading.

This is how I am restoring purchases.

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: _initApp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        // _gotoAppropriateScreen(context);
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder<List<PurchaseDetails>>(
            stream: inAppPurchase.purchaseStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              debugPrint(
                  "getInAppPurchaseStream connectionState: ${snapshot.connectionState}");
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                restorePurchases();
                return _roboLoadinAnim();
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  _getPurchases(snapshot.data!, context);
                  _gotoAppropriateScreen(context);
                  return _roboLoadinAnim();
                } else {
                  return _roboLoadinAnim();
                }
              } else {
                return _roboLoadinAnim();
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          return _roboLoadinAnim();
        }
      },
    );
  }

 Future<void> restorePurchases() async {
    bool isAvailable = await inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    debugPrint("restorePurchases: inAppPurchase.isAvailable(): $isAvailable");
    if (isAvailable) {
      await inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _initApp() async {
    debugPrint("LoadingScreen _initApp");
    var packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    appName = packageInfo.appName;
    packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
    buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
    version = packageInfo.version;
    ttsLanguages = await FlutterTts().getLanguages;
    await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
    await _loadUserSettingsFromHive();
    // if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // _clearTransactions();
    // }
  }
```

P.S *I am using a real device for the testing.*